# User not appearing but exists, cannot give it sudo privileges

Tags: permissions, login, 20.04, sudo, users

My user has been edited somehow so it does not appear on login or in my settings. However, I can still login if I use not listed and type it in, and if I try and add a user with the same name this is what happens:

```
jacob@jacob-desktop ~> sudo adduser jacob
adduser: The user `jacob' already exists.
```

This began happening after I changed my default shell to fish from bash after a clean install.

I have made myself a root user editing visudo, but i get the error `visudo: /etc/sudoers: Permission denied` when I don't use sudo although I am a confirmed root user as you can see below.

```
jacob@jacob-desktop ~ [1]> id jacob
uid=1000(jacob) gid=1000(jacob) groups=1000(jacob),4(adm),24(cdrom),27(sudo),29(audio),30(dip),46(plugdev),120(lpadmin),131(lxd),132(sambashare)
```

```
jacob@jacob-desktop ~> sudo whoami
[sudo] password for jacob: 
root
```

I have also tried to edit GDM with no success. I am not sure if giving root and sudo access is the right way to go as it seems I need to have it appear on login and in settings before I can do so.

Any help would be appreciated, I'm very stumped at this point.

[image: My Users tab in settings.]

Comment: `whoami` and `sudo whoami` should give different output, try it and see. If you want to use `visudo` you need to prepend `sudo`, thus `sudo visudo`. You (jacob) are member of the sudo-group already, so there is no reason to edit `/etc/sudoers`.

Comment: You are not supposed to be able to read or edit `/etc/sudoers` without root privileges. That file is root owned with chmod 0440.

Comment: @mook765 `jacob@jacob-desktop ~> whoami 
jacob
`
`jacob@jacob-desktop ~> sudo whoami
root
`.

Comment: @GunnarHjalmarsson ok, so do you think that file would have anything to do with getting my user back into the login screen and settings?

Comment: @mook765 Thank you for the input, and would you have any idea why this user isn't showing up? Or where I should look to find the cause?

Comment: @jakeant2 That's how it should be. You see that you can use `sudo` and you need to use `sudo` for actions which require elevated privileges, such as `visudo`. You don't need to edit the `/etc/sudoers`-file, all is fine. I can't help you with the problem that you are not listed in the login screen, I don't use GDM, but I'm sure some other user can help you with that.

Comment: No, I don't think `/etc/sudoers` has anything to do with your problem.

Comment: @GunnarHjalmarsson sounds good, thank you!

Answer (score 0):

One thing comes to mind: GDM is patched in Ubuntu on Xorg to be started with `/bin/bash` instead of upstream's `/bin/sh`. Possibly `fish` isn't compatible with that configuration.

Comment: Any way I could go about editing this? I did edit `bin` files so it is definitely possible.

Comment: @jakeant2: Well, it's just a vague theory. But it's the first line in `/etc/gdm3/Xsession` I'm thinking of.